# Error boton nulo eventos js

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

Al querer crear un evento a un botón por medio de una función anónima, me lanza el error botón is null, como puedo solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Operador this</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Operador this</h1>
        <p>
            <h2>precioname:</h2>
            <button id="boton">Click</button>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código JS

```
'use strict'

var boton = document.querySelector("#boton");

boton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.style.color = "red";
});
```

Comment: He replicado tu código tanto aquí como en este [codepen](https://codepen.io/ricardo-dlc/pen/RwKymmZ?editors=1111) y parece funcionar como se espera, al hacer clic en el botón, este cambia el color de su texto a rojo. ¿Hay alguna otra información que estes omitiendo?

Comment: Por si las moscas, colocale la palabra defer a tu script, para que te cargue el documento completo primero.Quizas no lo está leyendo

Comment: Yo te diría que hagas un window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{...codigo...}). Parece una tontería, pero a mi a veces me pasa lo mismo que a ti, y cuando empecé a haecr los loaders, me funcionan siempre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo probaría mejor a seleccionar el botón de la siguiente manera.

```
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
```

El resto de código parece estar bien y debería funcionar siempre que tu zona de script esté después de la declaración del botón.